# React.map does not get the selected value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a list of items, that is shown correctly with mui list and I have made a button so I can edit the list but when I click on the item I get the value of the last item not the one I clicked on.

This is my function:

```
const listItems = (id) => {
    if (!liste) {
        <div>no data</div>
    } else {
        return (
            <List>
                <ListItemButton onClick={() => handleClick(id)}>
                    <ListItemText primary={liste?.[id]?.navn} />
                    {handleOpen(id) ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
                </ListItemButton>

                <Collapse in={handleOpen(id)} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                    <List component="div" disablePadding>
                        {liste
                            .filter((l) => l.tilhors_id === id)
                            .map((l) => {
                                return (
                                    <ListItemButton
                                        key={l.id}
                                        sx={{ pl: 4 }}
                                    >
                                        <ListItemText
                                            primary={
                                                <div>
                                                    {l.navn}
                                                </div>
                                            }
                                        />{l.beloeb}{console.log(l.id)}
                                        <EditPost open={openModal} handleOpen={handleOpenModal} id={l.id} navn={l.navn} beloeb={l.beloeb} />
                                        <Button>X</Button>
                                    </ListItemButton>
                                );
                            })}
                    </List>
                </Collapse>
                {liste.filter((k) => k.subtotal === id)
                    .map((k) => {
                        return (
                            <ListItemButton key={k.id}>
                                <ListItemText primary="Subtotal" />
                                {k.beloeb}
                            </ListItemButton>)
                    })}
            </List>
        );
    }
};
```

this is my EditPost:

```
<div>
        <ButtonIcon type='button' onClick={handleOpen} ><GrEdit/></ButtonIcon>
        <Modal tittel='Login' open={open} handleOpen={handleOpen} >
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    <div>
                        <Chip label={navn} color='info' />
                        <Controller
                            control={control}
                            name="beloeb"
                            render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value, ref } }) =>
                                <Text
                                    label="Beløb"
                                    onChange={onChange}
                                    onBlur={onBlur}
                                    selected={value}
                                />
                            }
                            type="number"
                            InputLabelProps={{
                                shrink: true,
                            }}
                        />
                    </div>
                        <CustomizedButtons type="submit" label="Gem" disabled={isLoading} />
                </form>
        </Modal>
    </div>
```

I just don't understand why it doesn't get the selected value

**EDIT**

[Here is a codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/list-example-8zj1y6?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Where is `id` coming from when passed as a prop to `listItems`? I would expect your `ListItemButton` `onClick` to have declared argument `id` that is then passed to `handleClick`, instead you are just passing that `listItems` prop.

Comment: @qslabs I have made a codesandebox so you can see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sandbox helps! I took a look at the DOM, a modal instance is declared per rendered list item. So, after initial render, if only the first list, containing one item, is expanded, you'll render the expected modal. If the first two lists are expanded, you've know created eight modal instances at the bottom of the DOM (elements with attribute `role` value "presentation") and thus the latest instance is opened.

I haven't coded this solution, but what I would do is remove `Modal` from `EditPost` so that you are not rendering multiple `Modal` instances; rendering a singular instance in `App.js` would be a more appropriate alternative. From there, dynamically generate the contents of the modal instance via props.

Comment: yes I moved the modal out and just moved placed the button in the list so the modal is only rendered once